# Blower motor run capacitor replacement

Tags: capacitor, motor

I need to replace the capacitors on a blower motor, they heated and leaked. I couldn't find much capacitors that are compatible with the casing and has the same rating as the old ones. I however managed to find this one on Digikey.

https://www.digikey.ca/short/z2jwbb

The original ones are two 'All Earth 50uf 250vac 60/50' connected in parallel acting as one capacitor.
The one I found on Digikey has 4 terminals, 2 on each side, while the old one only has 2, 1 on each side.

I tried reading the datasheet but couldn't find much information about the terminals connection. Why is there 4 terminals on the one I found and will it work if I replace the old ones with this one.

I have attached two images of the old ones.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mQ4GB.jpg]
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wALFV.jpg]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most likely the Nichicon EEC you found on Digikey is configured as a 'DC-link' - the terminals closest to each other are internally paralled. This simplifies wiring (saves you a junction) if you are using it as a filter (between a source and a load).

Note that the EEC capacitor does *not* appear to be a UL-recognized component; the original All-Earth is (the backwards UR logo on the bottom-left of the silkscreened area). I recommend you ensure your replacement parts are UL-recognized for safety reasons.

Comment: I was gonna ask if I could replace it with a higher VAC. Thank you very much. I found one that is UL-recognized with a higher VAC. It's not the same shape but I have room to make it fit.

Answer (score 2):

Digikey is not necessarily the best source for cULus marked motor run capacitors. Appliance parts shops such as AMRE Supply and HVAC parts distributors tend to have a good selection in stock.

Mouser has some as well, and will ship to Canada.

You can consider a higher voltage rating such as 370VAC if you have room, it might last longer.